# PHP: How to ensure image sent over POST has been fully transmitted(avoid partial uploads)

Tags: php, image, encryption

So I am sending an image as a POST variable like so:

```
$my_image = file_get_contents(Settings::$FILE_NAME);
$params = array(
            'image' => $my_image
);
...send params with curl...
```

So, on the other end, I use imagecreatefromstring() to get the string and convert it to an image. I want to make sure that the original image that was sent from A, arrives intact on B's end. I've been having issues with certain images not uploading fully and showing up partially gray. I want to make sure that the image that I receive at point B is an identical copy of that sent from A, otherwise I want to discard it.

**Question:**
What would be a good way of ensuring complete and correct transfer of the image from point A to point B using my current setup? Or is there a better way of sending the image?

Comment: Use an SSL connection between the two endpoints.

Comment: You also don't need `imagecreatefromstring`, you just need to write the string into a file, et voila, you have your image.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on imagecreatefromstring. I've modified my question to better describe what I am hoping to achieve.

Comment: You could do something like include the file size or a cryptographic hash in the POST request.